# Is it possible to specify custom name for a Google Font?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, font-family, google-font-api

Here is a sample CSS

```
h1 {
   font-family: 'header-font', arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
   font-family: 'paragraph-font', arial, serif;
}
```

Is it possible to load any remote Google Font (let say 'Lato') so that it's family name in CSS would be 'header-font'?

Edit: The idea behind this is to be able to easily swap fonts in a WP theme. Unfortunately using variables in CSS preprocessors is not an option in my case.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Would it not cause issues if a user had a local font matching your custom font name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google fonts: Define custom name in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172964/google-fonts-define-custom-name-in-css)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can give any name you want when you define the font family in the @font-face style declaration and use that name to reference it later in the stylesheet.

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: whateverYouWant;
  src: url('example.ttf'),
       url('example.eot');
       ... /* and so on */
}
```

Whatever you name the style as in the font-family property is how it will be referred to from the rest of the document.  However I don't know how it competes with local font files (so if you tried to name a custom font Arial I'm not sure what you would get - the custom font or the real Arial).  I don't know why you would do that anyway though.

Comment: This would only work if you are locally storing the font.  The google font has a predefined name.

Comment: No, this WILL work. Just be careful you name `font-family` something guaranteed to be unique, maybe with a website identifier like `font-family: 'abcweb-header-font;'`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hAvcp

Comment: So where is the Google font integration?

Comment: This does not answer the question. For example How would you call a googlefont and give it a custom name of 'my-website-generic'

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can to be honest.  The Google font has a predefined name when you view the google font.  See this for example: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Akronim

Its name is set as 'Akronim' and I dont think you can reference it by any other name.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, very easily. Once you located the font at Google, eg.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400&subset=latin-ext');
```

just direct your browser to the url specified:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400&subset=latin-ext
```

What you get back is the `@font-face` CSS item for the font (or fonts). Simply use this verbose version in your CSS instead of the original `@import` specification. You can freely rename the `font-family` item in any of these descriptions. Yes, you have to make sure there are no clashes with other fonts but the naming is completely up to you.

Comment: That's a good starting point, but be aware that the CSS returned by google font is dependent on the browser.