# Google fonts: Define custom name in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, google-font-api

Is it possible to define a custom name for Google fonts?

Eg. `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

How to use 'Open Sans' with custom name?

```
div {
   font-family: 'custom'; // to be same as 'Open Sans'
}
```

Using `@font-face` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259560/is-it-possible-to-specify-custom-name-for-a-google-font) is not possible, since I don't have `url` to source files (ttf, eot, woff, ...).

Links to source files on Google `cdn` would solve this issue.

Comment: You can get the links to the source files if you go to the url you're linking to: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans, unfortunately it doesn't give you all of the urls... it only gives the ones that are 'best' for your own browser

Comment: That url is not valid for `font-face`, so it can't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work in your case:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyCustomOpenSans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: 
        local('Open Sans'), 
        local('OpenSans'), 
        url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2'), 
        url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
p {font-family: "MyCustomOpenSans", sans-serif;}
</style>
```

I'm not sure if it's a stable enough because the URL will change if there's a new update to the font and I'm not sure if Google will ban access to the other URL.

**EDIT:**

The WOFF format is supported by IE9+, Firefox, Chrome etc.
Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

The WOFF2 format is less supported:
http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2

Comment: Thanks, I could get url from response just to be up to date.

Comment: I edited the answer. I added links for the browser support of the WOFF and WOFF2 formats.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to download the file asynchronously and apply a custom name for the font, but this would require to store the font file somewhere because the `src url` requires an `external url` or a `relative url`. So you can solve this problem properly unless you download the font, convert the font (http://onlinefontconverter.com -- it's free, even for copyrighted materials) and link it to your HTML document using `@font-face`.

Comment: You don't need to store files, remote url works fine.

Comment: Yep you can use any URL, whether it's a `relative url` or an `absolute url`. The absolute URL used above (in the answer I provided) **might** change. If it changes, the font won't be displayed on the website, so the only **decent**, **proper** of solving the issue is to download the font file if we want to set a custom name for the font-family (the OP request). Otherwise, you can use a `<link>` or JS code to constantly load the latest font file in your HTML DOM, but you can't change its font-family name.

Answer (score 1):

You could download the font and supply your own name for it using `@font-face {}`

Convert the font using [a font converter](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Then change the font name like this...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'super-wicked-font-yeahhh'; /* CHANGE HERE */
  src: url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'),
     url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

Then call the font using:

```
p {
  font-family: super-wicked-font-yeahhh;
}
```

Comment: This is the best option but the OP mentioned that he doesn't want to download the files. He wants to download the font directly from the Google CDN. On another note, the online font converter you provided doesn't work with copyrighted fonts. The only free font converter (which doesn't care about copyrights) is: http://onlinefontconverter.com/
You have no limitation on the number of fonts converted ... it's completely free.

Comment: Source:
http://typographyforlawyers.com/why-google-web-fonts-arent-really-open-source.html
Source:
https://www.google.com/fonts/attribution
Although you can download them and use them for free, some of them cannot be modified, thus you can't convert them on your own.
Source: https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#Any_Page_OK

Comment: Well, well... This is news to me. marked comment up.